# Whats The Diffrance between View And WITH common_table_expression in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I Am New To SQL SERVER, and Usually I stored `Select Query Result` In `VIEW`, But recently 
I figured out that we can also store our query result with `WITH` clause.

So, What is the practical difference between

`CREATE VIEW` as `SQL SELECT QUERY`

and

`WITH` (Comman Table Expression) as `SQL SELECT QUERY`

And, when should we use which one?

Answer (score 1):

yes.

```
CREATE VIEW
AS
WITH
   cteX AS (...),
   cteY AS (...),
   cteZ AS (...)
SELECT ...
GO
```